# UE4 Export render target on android

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Exporting a render target on android creates a png file that appears to be **not valid**. The exact same blueprint works fine on windows.

Any ideas if the Export Render Target node should work on mobile?

I am using v4.23 launcher edition... I have tried v4.19 as well, with the same results, using a clean project.

The last attachment is the png that gets exported...

[image: my export render target blueprint]

[image: Settings of my capture component]

[image: My render target texture]

[image: The actual PNG file being exported]

Comment: The problem with Export Render Target not being able to write on mobile seems to come from the ExportRenderTarget2DAsPNG function inside Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\ImageUtils.cpp.

The function above is successfully called even on mobile from the ExportRenderTarget function inside Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\KismetRenderingLibrary.cpp

Still have no idea why it won't work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I submitted it as a bug to Unreal, they were able to reproduce the issue. So it is a bug...

Here is a link to the issue tracker

https://issues.unrealengine.com/issue/UE-80840